# .Net components for Mono

Tags: .net, winforms, mono, components

Can anybody suggest any stable WinForms .Net components, that are compatible with Mono. 
As I know DevExpress and Infragistics still have a lot of Windows specific PInvoke calls which.

**UPDATE 1:**
I need WinForms .Net components with standart controls(TextBox,Buttons,Checkbox, Tree) which have common Look&Feel and a theme engine. Something similar to DevExpress .Net Winforms components, but with Mono compatibility.

Comment: You should ask about specific components that you need. As it is now, your question is too unfocused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a cross-platform (or Linux only) WinForms application, use GTK#.

There aren't many more options.
wxWidgets has a .NET/mono binding as well.


Then, look for custom GTK# controls.

However, this probably requires a rewrite, so why not just write a web-interface ?
e.g. make it a web-application and embed a webserver to listen on port 5000 or 9000.

Then, on start of your application, open the default webbrowser with URL http://localhost:5000

Comment: For an embedded webserver that works on Windows and Linux, try this: http://weblogs.asp.net/britchie/archive/2005/07/25/420512.aspx. You also

Comment: Technically, when you use GTK#, it's no longer a “WinForms application”.

Comment: @svick: True, but it still works on Windows [assuming you installed the GTK runtime] :)

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits